# Suitable method to determine whether a time-varying matrix is positive definite

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Consider a matrix function $t \mapsto P(t):\,\,[0,\infty)\mapsto\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Assume $P(t)=P^T(t)$ is continuous and bounded.

With a variable $x\in \mathbb R$, if $x^T\,P(t)\,x>0$ holds $\forall t$, $P(t)$ is positve definite.

What is a suitable method to check the definitness of a given $P(t)$ in this time-varying case? For the time-invariant case, i.e. $P \equiv const.$, I would consider the eigenvalues of $P$. However, time-varying eigenvaulues normally have different meenings, therefore, I'am not sure what to do here.

Comment: Surely the answer depends on problem context & detail?  You might exhibit a matrix valued function $A(t)$, for which $P(t)=A(t)A(t)^T$.  You might show $\det P(t)>0$ for all $t$ and that $P(1)$ is positive definite. (Which works only if $P(t)$ depends continuously on $t$.)

Comment: @kimchi lover. I added further assumptions "Assume $P(t)=P^T(t) $ is continuous and bounded. " Why the condition $\det P(t)>0$ needs $P(1)$?

Comment: As you know, $\det P(t)$ by itself does not prove $P(t)$ is positive definite.  If you know somehow that $P(t_0)$ is positive definite, and $P(t_1)$ is not positive definite, there must be a $t'\in[t_0,t_1]$ for which an eigenvalue vanishes, in which case $\det P(t')=0$.  So the conditions that $\forall t,\det P(t)>0$ and that $\exists t: P(t)\text{ is pos. def}$ together imply they all are.

Comment: Why don't you show an explicit example of the kind of $P(t)$ you are interested in.

Comment: I'am interested in general conditions, thats why an example I don't have. Thank you so far, this fact you explain I didn't knew. You mention that an eigenvalue vanishes. Is it possible as a criterion to check if all (time-varying) eigenvalues are positive for all time? Do you know a text book regarding the determinant conditions?